# Access variable of child form

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables, set

Using VB.Net

I have about 60 Child forms

Each have a variable with same name.

In Main form I want to set the value of the variable of the active child.

One way of doing that is like

```
Select Case Me.ActiveMdiChild.Name
  Case "formName"
    frmformName.Variable=0
```

I donot want to do that as it involves writing many cases and I may miss some.

Is there some other way of doing it .

I tried

```
Dim O as Object = Me.ActiveMdiChil

O.VariableName= 0
```

and its various variants but its not working

Comment: Consult your favorite vb.net language book about the *Interface* keyword.  All of these sixty forms (ugh) should implement the same interface.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that is with an Interface, example:

```
Public Interface IChildVariable
  Property Variable() As Integer
End Interface

Public Class Form1
  Implements IChildVariable

  Private _MyVariable As Integer

  Public Property Variable() As Integer Implements IChildVariable.Variable
    Get
      Return _MyVariable
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
       _MyVariable = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Then you can just have a single check point:

```
If TypeOf Me.ActiveMdiChild Is IChildVariable Then
  DirectCast(Me.ActiveMdiChild, IChildVariable).Variable = 0
Else
  ''Throw Exception
End If
```